# Get all non null properties from all objects in a ManagementObjectCollection

Tags: c#, foreach, wmi

I'm trying to simplify these two `foreach` loops but I cant seem to get it. it uses the `management` library which gets information about the OS, there's about 30 different items but I just want one. At the moment I'm scrolling through them all and display the one I want when it pops up.

```
try
{
    ManagementClass Management = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");

    foreach (ManagementObject Object in Management.GetInstances())
    {
        foreach (PropertyData Data in Object.Properties)
        {
            if (Data.Name.Equals("CSName")  && (Data.Value != null))
            {
                TxtBody.Text += "<br><font color = red>" + Data.Name + ": " + Data.Value + "</font>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Surely I can just put something like `TxtBody.text += Management.PropertyData.CSName` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least one loop but to avoid the use of nested loops you can use LINQ.

You could use LINQ like this:

```
foreach (PropertyData Data in Management.GetInstances()
                              .SelectMany(Object => Object.Properties
                              .Where(Data => Data.Name.Equals("CSName") 
                              && (Data.Value != null))))
{
     TxtBody.Text += "<br><font color = red>" + Data.Name + ": " + Data.Value + "</font>";
}
```

Comment: that would simplify it abit more but i was thinking a way to do it without a loop and just directly refrence the CSName

Comment: @Will...You need to iterate through. BTW you need a loop for that but you can use linq to remove nested `foreach`.

Comment: @Will I agree with S.Akbari. You are iteratively doing something for each item who's name is "CSName", thus a loop is required. You can (and should) however avoid the use of nested loops as this is a typical implementation of quadratic time complexity (very...very slow)

Comment: @Will It would be great if you also vote for an answer when you accept it. You can click up arrow near the answer to upvote. It's recommended and reasonable. More information http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use [the indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.item(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (ManagementObject Object in Management.GetInstances())
{ 
    var value = Object["CSName"];
    if (value == null)
        continue;
    TxtBody.Text += "<br><font color = red>" + "CSName" + ": " + value + "</font>";
}
```

---

You can also avoid loops at all using some LINQ and String.Join:

```
var propName = "CSName";

var keyValues = Management
    .GetInstances()
    .Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .Select(obj =>
    new
    {
        name = propName,
        value = obj[propName]
    })
    .Where(obj => 
         obj.value != null);

var result =
    String.Join(
        "",
        keyValues
            .Select(kv =>
                String.Format("<br><font color = red>{0} : {1} </font>", kv.name, kv.value)));

TxtBox.Text += result;
```

Comment: ok that looks good, i need at least one foreach loop so ill go with that, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not claiming it's simplest but a simpler and elegant want and adoptable method to achieve result.

```
foreach (var pValue in management.GetInstances().Cast<ManagementObject>()
    .Select(managementObject => managementObject.Properties.Cast<PropertyData>()
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "CSName"))
    .Where(pValue => pValue != null))
{
    TxtBody.Text += "<br><font color = red>" + pValue.Name + ": " + pValue.Value + "</font>";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Any particular C# version are you using. I'm on VS 2015 and no issue.

Comment: just c# form, vs 2015, 4.5.2 framework. I wanted to try yours because i saw "firstOrDefault" which i thought might fix the error of getting 4 copys of CSName. im not getting any errors in the code, its just not showing up

Comment: Here is gist of full code. https://gist.github.com/saleem-mirza/28c4f09029a23a46a0c7

Comment: as in not returning anything, textbox is blank, thanks ill look into that code

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is only 1 item in there that you want you can do:

```
var data = Management.SelectMany(_ => _.Properties).FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Name == "CSName" && _.Value != null);
if (data != null)
    TxtBody.Text += "<br><font color = red>" + data.Name + ": " + data.Value + "</font>";
```

Answer (score -1):

A purely LINQ solution:

```
new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem").GetInstances().ToList()
    .ForEach(instance => instance.Properties
        .Where(property => property.Name.Equals("CSName") && property.Value != null).ToList()
            .ForEach(property => TxtBody.Text += "<br><font color = red>" + property.Name + ": " + property.Value + "</font>"));
```

Comment: The .ToList() is throwing me an error but ive used another method and it works